# TcpClient connection attempts in C#

Tags: c#

I have a simple program. I wanted to check if the server actually is online so my users can connect to it before doing stuff, so on the form load event I have the following:

```
 private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            tcp.Connect("110.174.194.138", 8484);
            MessageBox.Show("siccces");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("failed");
        }
        if (tcp.Connected)
        {
            //do whatever once program has connected.
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FAILED");
        }
    }
```

It all works fine when the server is online (and it can connect). It connects in 0.1 seconds and nothing bad happens .However, when the server is off, it attempts to reconnect about 5 times I think, which takes up to 15 seconds. How can I make it attempt to connect only once so I can show a failed message instantly?

Thanks.

Comment: How you so sure about this. did you put debug point in your code?

Comment: What makes you think it retries 5 times?

Comment: This is something that you should probably consider doing on a different thread so you don't tie up the main thread and lock the UI.  You could disable your controls that will raise events that will do anything with the TCP connection, until the background work is finished, having verified a responsive/unresponsive server.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4584514/2530848)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : How to set test TCP connection timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583873/c-sharp-how-to-set-test-tcp-connection-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Within your `tcp` class, you would need to modify the code to time out after a given time period. You will have to test the connection to see if it is up within the time period given, and if not you will have to handle the results. There are multiple ways of doing this, so just do a Google search for timeout for the socket method you are using.